How can I make fastest calculation speed for given condition for numpy array?
I made category as below.
1~4 : 0
5~9 : 1
10~15 : 2

I have a numpy array as below.
np.array([2, 5, 10, 13, 7, 9])

How can I make fastest way to change above numpy array based on given conditioin as below?
np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])

Because I think 'for loop' will consume lots of time.
Is there any way to make fastest time calculation?

how would you consider values outside of the range given?

You can also use np.searchsorted as below:
a = np.array([2, 5, 10, 13, 7, 9])
np.searchsorted([4, 9, 15], a)
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64)


labels = np.array([23, 45, 87])
labels[np.searchsorted([4, 9, 15], a)]
array([23, 45, 87, 87, 45, 45])


Assuming you have positive integers and intervals are successive, you could use np.digitize:
a = np.array([2, 5, 10, 13, 7, 9])
np.digitize(a, [4, 9, 15], right=True)

Output: array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])
To make it a bit more complex, if you want to pass a lower bound and have custom labels:
a = np.array([2, 5, 10, 13, 7, 9])
bins = [0, 4, 9, 15]
labels = [23, 45, 87]
np.array(labels)[np.digitize(a, bins, right=True)-1]

Output: array([23, 45, 87, 87, 45, 45])

Cool. That's awesome. What if I want to put another value such as 23, 45, 87 instead of 0, 1, 2?

Note that this gives 9 to be in category 2 instead of category 1. Seems by default, it is open right. You should close right. i believe digitize has the right parameter that you can set to true

@Onyambu of course, thanks! The worst thing is I checked the default parameter and my brain must have read True (pandas's cut has right=True by default)!

If the category keys are integer values, as in the given example, you can use them as array indexes.
# Hard code the categories
cat = np.array([
    0,                # Leave unused category keys empty
    0, 0, 0, 0,       # Cat 0
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,    # Cat 1
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2  # Cat 2
])

cat[np.array([2, 5, 10, 13, 7, 9])]
# >>> array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1])

